# Can we send two different invite for same event in outlook using graph api microsoft

Tags: python-2.7, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to send two different invites with different bodies for users.
example requirements:

1. There are interviewer and applicant who needs to notify
2. we want to create event and send them with different body invite.
3. In Google Meet there is an option for [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) using that we can do this task.

Is there any way in Microsoft Outlook to use REST graph API for the same task event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Graph API does not support your scenario. Being said that, please consider raising user voice [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for the feature ask that you have so that it could be considered for future implementations.

Hope this helps. Thank you.